# Fabric.js Change rect fill size

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

After changing rect width and height, it's fill pattern doesn't fit anymore.

[image]

I'm trying to reset fill sizes, but it is not working.

```
rect.setWidth(width_h);
rect.setHeight(height_v);


if (rect.fill.source)
{
    rect.fill.source.width = width_h;
    rect.fill.source.height = height_v;
}   

rect.setLeft(width_h);
rect.setTop(height_v);

rect.setCoords();

canvas.renderAll();
```

I've tried another approach then.

```
rect.setWidth(width_h);
rect.setHeight(height_v);
if (rect.fill.source)
{
                        img = new fabric.Image(rect.fill.source)

                        img.scaleToWidth(rect.getWidth());
                        rect.setFill(img);
}   

rect.setLeft(width_h);
rect.setTop(height_v);

rect.setCoords();

canvas.renderAll();
```

Still no luck, all rects became just white.

Would someone please advise, how do I reset pattern size for rect fill.

Comment: try renderAll() on your canvas after change width and height. It will redraw the forms with the new dimensions

Comment: Nope, for some reason it is not.